# working with files in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have a problem writing an array to a file as follow:

```
for(i=1;i<tblRows;i++)
{
    facID=tbl.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML;
    money=tbl.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML
    content+=facID+','+money+"\n";
    result+=parseFloat(money);
}
alert(content);
window.open('data:text/txt;charset=utf-8,'+escape(content));
```

in alert mode i get the result and the data comes in new line after  \n but in writting to file ,all of my data will write in a line .
how can i write my data in a file as follow?

```
12236545,4,269731,88468,13960620
1/11,9
2/22,8
3/33,7
4/44,4
```

thanks

Comment: You have unmatched braces -- there's an extra `}`. Which code is supposed to be inside the loop?

Comment: `escape()` is deprecated, you should use `encodeURIComponent()` now. But maybe the right solution is to use base 64 encoding.

Comment: thanks for your help but it did not work

Comment: Are you saving to Windows or Unix? On Windows, line breaks are `\r\n`

Answer (score 0):

Windows there is the two character sequence: '\r\n'

Comment: Hello m.rezaei --No problem. Can you upvote my answer.  Parmdeep Chahbra